# Rails 5 query association must comply with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In in a Rails 5 application we have a `User` and a `Job` models which have many `skills` through `AttachedSkills`.

AttachedSkills is a polymorphic table. It saves users or jobs skills.

##### User Model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attached_skills, as: :skillable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :skills, through: :attached_skills
end
```

##### Job Model

```rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attached_skills, as: :skillable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :skills, through: :attached_skills
end
```

##### Skills Model

```rb
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attached_skills
end
```

##### AttachedSkill Model

```
class AttachedSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :skillable, polymorphic: true
end
```

In the skills table let's say I have skills with id 640 and 641.

I need a query that fetches all users that have both skills. They must have at least these two skills.

How can I write such a query?

- Ruby 2.6.6
- Rails 5.2.5
- Postregesql

Comment: If I understand correctly then `User.joins(:skills).where(skills: {id: [640,641]}).group(:id).having(Arel.star.count.eq(2))` should return all the `User` with both of those `Skill`s

Comment: @engineersmnky `at least`

Comment: @LamPhan right so it must have these 2 skills and we are filtering down to these 2 skills ("WHERE skills.id IN (640,641)"). Which means that unless the `User` can have the same skill twice "HAVING COUNT(*) = 2" ensures they have both of them. They may have many many others but that means nothing to this query.

Comment: @engineersmnky  your're right